# NSSetを元にテーブルビューを表示する際にセクション分けを行いたい

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, coredata

初めて質問させて頂きます。
読みにくい部分があるかもしれませんが、ご容赦下さい。

CoreDataより２階層のテーブルビューを作ろうとしています。

データモデルは以下の通り

・主クラス
　[属性]名称、区分１
　[関係]明細(多)

・明細クラス
　[属性]名称、区分２
　[関係]主(１)

第１階層のテーブルビューは自動生成されたコードの
NSFetchedResultsController の sectionNameKeyPath: で
主クラスの区分１ごとにセクション分けすることが出来ました。

第２階層でも同様に、明細クラスを区分２ごとにセクション分けしたいのですが、
主クラスよりNSSetで取得した明細クラスを、どのように扱えば良いのか分かりません。

ソートしてNSArrayにする方法は分かるので、
単純にループさせてセットする方法なら思いつくのですが、
第１階層のNSFetchedResultsController のように
簡単にセクション分けした２次元配列にする方法があればご教授下さい。

Answer (score 1):

主クラスは、CoreDataにたいするqueryなので、sortDescriptorや、適合条件等をつけてできます。

しかし、ここでの明細クラスは、主クラスのqueryの先に付いている、setですから、NSSetのメソッドをつかってなんとかするしかないでしょう。

- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors

をつかえば、ソートはできるようです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
現状ではsortedArrayUsingDescriptors:で並べ替えた後、for-inで回しながらfilteredArrayUsingPredicate:で抽出してセクション分けを行っています。

NSFetchedResultsControllerのように簡単にセクション指定出来て、indexPathをそのまま使えるようなものを期待したのですが、無いのであれば現状のままで行こうと思います。